# Does WSASend() hide batching of large buffers?

Tags: tcp, buffer, winsock

I'm testing large buffers right now and I am setting it in WSABUF and calling `WSASend()` next.

Thing though, is that `WSARecv()` just handed it back that large buffer in one go.

Does that make sense?

Where is the limit of `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()` with with respect to large buffers?

It seems that batching is happening in the background and all of that is hidden behind the abstraction.

If that is the case, I would like that always happenning to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is the socket send and receive buffer size respectively.

`WSASend()` blocks while the socket send buffer is full and returns when everything has been transferred to the socket send buffer. Meanwhile, asynchronously, TCP is removing data from the socket send buffer, turning it into TCP segments in a way which you cannot control, and passing the segments to the IP layer, which in turn turns them into IP packets, again in a way which you cannot control.

`WSARecv()` blocks while there is no data in the socket receive buffer, and returns when all the data in the socket receive buffer has been transferred to the application, up to the limit supplied by the application. That could be as little as one bye, or the entire application buffer, or anything in between, depending entirely on the granularity of what is received.

All this refers to blocking mode. Non-blocking mode is similar except that there are error returns instead of blocks above.